# Line spacing in CV

Tags: itemize, line-spacing

I have one question regarding how can I adjust line spacing in Latex.

I think...it's kind of an easy problem...however...I don't have any idea about solving this problem since I'm not familiar with Latex grammar.

The problem is that I want to **reduce the line spacing** in the areas marked in red in the attached picture.
[image]

I also attached latex codes of that part as follows:

[image]

I hope that I can receive some assistance regarding my circumstance. Thank you so much.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please, provide a small but complete document beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` with code showed as image in your question, which demonstrate your problem.

Comment: @Zarko As you have mentioned, I changed the source code picture to aid your understanding of my problem. Could you give me some advice?

Comment: Picture of your source code is not of big help. It can be compiled, e.g. we need to rewrite what is not fun. Help us to help you and please copy code from your editor and past it to question.

Answer (score 1):

The top separator is controlled by the key `topsep`  -- simply set it to 0pt or whatever is desired separation

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt]
  \item Item 1
  \item Item 2
  \item Item 3
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

To set this globally, use

```
\setlist[itemize]{topsep=0pt}
```

Comment: Thank you for your considerable comment regarding my problem. I was able to solve this issue thanks to your suggestions. Thank you so much!!! Take care!!!

Comment: @Hwang - request accept the answer by clicking the green tick on the left of the answer -- regards